# Optimization of a closed box

Tags: calculus, optimization

A box with a rectangular base and top must have a volume of 9m^3. The length of the base is three times the width material for the base costs `$`5 per square meter. Material for the sides costs `$`4 per square meter. Material for the top costs `$`3 per square meter. Find the dimension of the box the minimize the cost.

I understand how to solve for an open-top box. The lid is throwing me for a loop. I believe that you can describe the box with equation f(x)=24x^2+(96/x) but am unsure.

Comment: So do you mean that the material has no thickness?

Comment: there is no thickness to the material as far as I can tell from the question.

Comment: All related questions I can find are either open-topped or only are about cost

Comment: What does the function $f$ represent, and how did you arrive at it?

Comment: f(x) is being used to describe the cost of the box, therefore, my next step is to try to minimize the cost(f(x)) to get the smallest dimensions. I arrived at it by saying, f(x)=cost=5(L*w)+3(L*w)+8(L*h)+8(h*w), then simplifying and combining like terms.

Comment: Then used that f(x) equation to find f'(x)=0 to find critical points. graphed it and found that f(x) is the smallest when x is 1.26m. L=3x, L= 3.78m. h= (9m^3)/(3x^2), h=1.89m. so the dimensions of the box optimized for cost would be 3.78mX1.26mX1.89m, LxWxH. Then checked this by solving for volume to be = 9 meters cubed.

Comment: Youst say  f(x)=\text{cost}=5(Lw)+3(Lw)+8(Lh)+8(hw),$ but there's no $x$ on the right-hand side.  Also, you have to impose the condition $Lwh=9$ before you take derivatives.  You may have gotten the right answer (I don't know), but if so, the description is incorrect.

Comment: "there is no thickness to the material as far as I can tell from the question"               Forget this stupid problem. Let's get a Nobel Prize out to whoever discovered or invented this material.

Comment: x is equal to w as that is the smallest form of measure.  f(w)=cost=5(Lw)+3(Lw)+8(Lh)+8(hw) and  f(x)=cost=5(Lw)+3(Lw)+8(Lh)+8(hw) are the same I forgot to add that to my post, sorry. In the original post I had this, f(x)=24x^2+(96/x). which is the simplified form of f(w)=cost=5(Lw)+3(Lw)+8(Lh)+8(hw) and  f(x)=cost=5(Lw)+3(Lw)+8(Lh)+8(hw).

Comment: This is a trivial problem to formulate and solve. But in doing so, I discovered an apparent  bug in YALMIP. I started by solving the problem, then seeing that you got a better solution, and yours is feasible, so the solution: I obtained must be wrong. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/yalmip/nNpuz3Dan94

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- The solution for a box with a top doesn't differ substantially from that of an open-top box.  The area of the top and base are the same—namely $\ 3w^2\ $ square metres, where $\ w $ is the width of the base in metres—so the cost of the top and base is $\ 15w^2+9w^2=24w^2\ $ as opposed to $\ 15w^2\ $ for the base alone. So whatever method you used to solve the problem for the open-top box should still work for the box with a top if you simply add $\ 9w^2\ $ to the cost of the former.
- If the dimensions of the box are $\ w\times3w\times h\ $, then its volume is $\ 3w^2h\ $, so if the volume is $9$ cubic metres you must have $\ h=\frac{3}{w^2}\ $. The total area of the two sides with length $\ w\ $ is $\ 2\times wh=\frac{6}{w}\ $ and that of the two sides with length $\ 3w\ $ is $\ 2\times3wh=\frac{18}{w}\ $.  If I multiply the areas of the top, bottom and sides by their costs per unit area and add them, I get $\ 24w^2+ \frac{96}{w}\ $ for the total cost, corresponding to the equation you believe you can use to describe the box.
- Since the expression for the cost is a function of a single variable $\ w\ $, the width of the base, you can find the minimum cost by differentiating this function and finding the value of the width for which the derivative is zero.